# How to pass variable from foreach to view in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

I want to count each location in my Job table by using location_id in my job table with id in location table. below code, I can count result correctly but I don't know how to pass this variable to the view. Please help?

//my code

```
public function index(){
            $location = Location::all();
            $count_location = [];
            foreach ($location as $locations){
                $count_location = Job::where('location_id', $locations->id)->count();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to send? An array of counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) and `view()` to pass location with counted jobs to the view:

```
public function index(){
    return view('view.name', [
        'locations' => Location::withCount('jobs')->get()
    ]);
}
```

In the view:

```
@foreach ($locations as $location)
    {{ $location->name }} has {{ $location->jobs_count }} jobs
@endforeach
```

Comment: Work perfect Alexey Mezenin, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can return the collection of locations to the view and then loop through each object in the collection like so:

```
return view('index', [
    'locations'=> $locations,
]);
```

Then in your `index.blade.php` you can use something like a `@foreach` or `@forelse` loop

```
@foreach ($locations as $location)
     {{ $location->id }}
@endfoeach
```

**EDIT**

From the looks of it you would be better off defining a relationship between locations and jobs (i.e. a "many to many" or "one to many" relationship). this would allow you to get the counts for jobs at given locations very easily like so:

```
$location->jobs->count()
```

Eloquent relationships are explained in the documentation here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I want to count location with this $count_location from foreach

Comment: Your `foreach` has a couple of issues 1) You are constantly redefining `$count_location` each time you iterate through the loop so it will only have the jobs count for the last location. 2) Unless you are wanting to aggregate all jobs counts in one variable, you will need to setup an array of collection which you can then pass to the view.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient if construct your query to fetch the count of related models instead of looping through all the results.

Have a look at [Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) in the documentations.

For example, to get the count of all jobs related to a location, you could do:

```
$locations = App\Location::withCount('jobs')->get();

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    echo $location->jobs_count;
}
```

You need to adjust the code according to your models structure.

Comment: you are right but I want to count the job that has specific Id from location id. I don't want to count all job or all location.for example how many jobs that have location in USA(?), Canada(?), Australla(?) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
public function index(){
            $locations = Location::all();
            return view('index', compact('locations'));

    }
```

In your Location model make a relationship by adding this

```
public function jobs(){
 return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}
```

In your index view do this

```
            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                {{$location->jobs->count}}
            @endforeach
```

**Please note that `Job` should be there in your your model**